# Is request.user.is_authenticated() necessary here?

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication

I am writing a view only for staff users.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        # show something to staff
    else:
        return my_view_404(request)
```

It this permission check enough? Any flaw? Or should I check request.user.is_authenticated()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to check `is_authenticated()`.  Non-authenticated users will have an `AnonymousUser` object in `request.user`, and that type of object should respond `False` to all `is_staff` checks without exception.

Answer (score 0):

No need as request.user.is_staff will check both authentication and staff status.